# Produce/Consume to Remote Kafka Does not Work

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python, pykafka

I have set up a AWS EC2 instance running Apache Kafka 0.8 via a Bitnami AMI image. The server properties are pretty much default (Kafka located at localhost:9092 and zookeeper located at localhost:2181).

When I SSH into the machine, I can produce/consume data using the scripts provided by Kafka, located at kafka/bin.
To produce I run the following command:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

To Consume:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

This works correctly, thus I have determined that Kafka is functioning correctly. Next I attempted to produce/consume from my machine, using the python library pykafka:

```
client = KafkaClient(hosts = KAFKA_HOST)
topic = client.topics[sys.argv[1]]

try:
    with topic.get_producer(max_queued_messages=1, auto_start=True) as producer:
        while True:
            for i in range(10):
                message = "Test message sent on: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M%p on %B %d, %Y"))
                encoded_message = message.encode("utf-8")
                mess = producer.produce(encoded_message)
except Exception as error:
    print('Something went wrong; printing exception:')
    print(error)
```

And I consume as follows:

```
client = KafkaClient(hosts = KAFKA_HOST)
topic = client.topics[sys.argv[1]]

try:    
    while True:
        consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer(auto_start=True)
        for message in consumer:
            if message is not None:
                print (message.offset, message.value)
except Exception as error:
    print('Something went wrong; printing exception:')
    print(error)
```

These snippets run without errors or exceptions, but no messages are produced or consumed, not even the ones created via the local scripts.

I have confirmed that both ports 9092 and 2181 are open via telnet.
My questions are as follows:

- Is there a way to debug such problems and find the root cause? I would expect the library to throw an exception if there is some connectivity issues.
- What is going on?

Comment: Just curious: Why such an old version of Kafka?

Comment: Also, by default Kafka wouldn't be listening externally from EC2. It's not as simple as a port forward https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: in addition to opening any ports and permissions on your AWS EC2 instance, you may have to change the `listeners` property from `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` to `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`. Using the IP Address of `0.0.0.0` allows Kafka to listen to connections from outside the machine whereas having `localhost` only allows connecting from within the same machine.